# Other Ways to read specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a small problem while reading columns.
My columns are ["onset1", "onset2", "onset3"], and I want to read the values from excel. But each of the Dataframe has different column names so I need to change the name each time, it's a waste of time.

Wondering if they are any way to read in an efficient way instead of reading df["onset1"].iloc[-1], df["onset2"].iloc[-1]....
(I am thinking of reading the top of the alphabet, like df["V].iloc[-1], df["W].iloc[-1] )

[image]

Comment: Does your data start in column A?

Comment: Yes! But after A is E then I then M

Comment: Either way, you probably should just use `iloc` and index both axes.

Comment: Put it in the front? or how to ?

Comment: e.g. `df.iloc[-1, 0]`, changing the `0` as necessary depending on the column.

Comment: OH!! Amazing! It's my first time to know it